# Rollback in procedure called over dblink

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have strange situation

It's bit hard to explain but I'll do my best

There are 3 different database included

From DB1 I call function on DB2 (over dblink)

That procedure calls another procedure that inserts data into table on DB3

Function on DB2 has EXCEPTION handle that should rollback everything that it did in case of exception

I did example run, and everything went well (there was no error) but insert from procedure 3 was not rollbacked and I have to rollback from DB1 to truly rollback

If i commit from db1, row is inserted

Am I doing something wrong and is there a way to rollback directly from function on db2

Here is some example code:

```
--DB1
PROCEDURE 1
BEGIN
    x := function2@dblink_to_db2();
END;

--DB2
FUNCTION 2
BEGIN
    procedure3();
    RAISE SOME EXCEPTION;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        do_something_else();
        RETURN 0;
END;

PROCEDURE 3
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tableA@dblink_to_db3 VALUES ... ;
END;
```

So no error is raised but insert into table on db3 is not rollbacked

Comment: i do not have 3 dbs to test it.  a call via a dblink is always a transaction. regardless of whether you make an insert or select. After a select, you also have to do commit or rollback. what happens if you raise exception in procedure3?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Situation is the same. If i raise exception in procedure3, do rollback there in handler, same situation, row inserted is still visible from db1.
btw, situation is happening with database from another company. So for tests i used only 2 databases, db1 for first procedure, db2 for second and third, and insert from db2 back to db1 over dblink. So if you have 2 databases, that is a way you can recreate

Answer (score 0):

**You must be having a commit somewhere in your code either before the raise exception or in Procedure3**. I just tested the below code and it rolledback everything before the exception. Please ignore the naming conventions, had to go due to time constraint.

**Database 3**
    CREATE TABLE temp
    (col1 NUMBER);

```
create or replace procedure testp(i number)
as
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO temp VALUES (i);
END;
/
```

**Database2**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DLR_TRANS.testf(i number)
return number
as
e exception;
BEGIN
    testp@TO_DB3(i);
    RAISE e;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

**database1**

```
declare
x number;
BEGIN
    x := testf@TO_DB2(15);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'x = ' || x );
    commit;
END;
```

x returns 0 due to exception in DB2's function.

And below is the data when I ran the below statement on DB3

```
select * from temp;
```

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: There is no COMMIT nowhere in code. At first I tried to put commit in it (due to logging), but then it raised error:
ORA-02055: distributed update operation failed; rollback required 
ORA-02064: distributed operation not supported 
So that commit was removed. 
Will try to play a little bit more to figure out why it works for you and not for me. Thanks

Comment: EDIT: Copied entire code (with minor adjustment) and executed it, row is inserted in my case. In test I did use only 2 database-s (so testp is on database 1 in your example), but as I said, same happened when 3 database-s were used.DB version is: 11.2.0.3.0 on both database. Don't know what could be a problem

Comment: huh, looks like my response was not published or may be I missed it, but what is the minor adjustment you made to the code? This should work irrespective of Oracle Version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have "handled" the exception in [function 2].  You should not put the exception block in [function 2] at all.  And let the exception propagate up to [procedure 1].  Here you will implicitly or explicitly rollback.

If you must have an exception block in [function 2] then you should have a [raise] at the end.  Handling the exception like this is saying [I have **handled** it and for all practical purposes the caller of this should not think anythibg bad has happened]

Comment: Yes, that is intended behavior. Procedure from DB1 doesn't want any errors raised, function in DB2 does everything it needs to check what went wrong, alert who it needs and so on (that is in do_something_else(); call)

Comment: Then use some other technique to communicate the failure.  E.g. function can return 1 for success and you use x to roll back or commit